# Oracle: group in one row all the data filtering by max and min

Tags: oracle

i have this data

```
   RESERVATION      PREFIX  FLIGHT  ORIGIN  DESTINATION DATE_FLIGHT
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    111             LA      123    LAX        MIA       2020-02-01 00:00
    111             LA      122    MIA        SCL       2020-02-01 10:30
    111             LA      667    MIA        SCL       2020-02-03 14:15
    111             LA      882    SCL        ARG       2020-02-03 16:00
    111             LA      111    SCL        ARG       2020-02-03 23:00
    111             LA      966    SCL        ARG       2020-02-03 23:30
    111             LA      622    SCL        ARG       2020-02-05 08:00
```

I need to filter through all the information and just leave the data of the first and last flight in one row

```
RESERVATION     PREFIX_min  FLIGHT_min  ORIGIN_min  DESTINATION_min DATE_FLIGHT_min  PREFIX_max  FLIGHT_max  ORIGIN_max  DESTINATION_max    DATE_FLIGHT_max
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
111             LA          123         LAX             MIA         2020-02-01 00:0         LA       622            SCL        ARG              2020-02-05 08:00
```

Comment: HOw do you determine that flight 123 is the 1st flight, and not 122?  They both have the same date?

Comment: you're right , its date_flight its a time_stamp value , I will edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any (inefficient) self-joins. Just use aggregation with `KEEP DENSE_RANK FIRST|LAST`:

```sql
SELECT reservation,
       MIN( prefix      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS prefix_min,
       MIN( flight      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS flight_min,
       MIN( origin      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS origin_min,
       MIN( destination ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS desination_min,
       MIN( date_flight ) AS date_flight_min,
       MIN( prefix      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS prefix_max,
       MIN( flight      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS flight_max,
       MIN( origin      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS origin_max,
       MIN( destination ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date_flight ) AS desination_max,
       MAX( date_flight ) AS date_flight_max
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY reservation;
```

so for your test data:

```sql
create table table_name ( RESERVATION, PREFIX, FLIGHT, ORIGIN, DESTINATION, DATE_FLIGHT ) AS
SELECT 111, 'LA', 123, 'LAX', 'MIA', DATE '2020-02-01' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'LA', 122, 'MIA', 'SCL', DATE '2020-02-01' + INTERVAL '10:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'LA', 667, 'MIA', 'SCL', DATE '2020-02-03' + INTERVAL '14:15' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'LA', 882, 'SCL', 'ARG', DATE '2020-02-03' + INTERVAL '16:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'LA', 111, 'SCL', 'ARG', DATE '2020-02-03' + INTERVAL '23:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'LA', 966, 'SCL', 'ARG', DATE '2020-02-03' + INTERVAL '23:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'LA', 622, 'SCL', 'ARG', DATE '2020-02-05' + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

this outputs:

> ```
> RESERVATION | PREFIX_MIN | FLIGHT_MIN | ORIGIN_MIN | DESINATION_MIN | DATE_FLIGHT_MIN     | PREFIX_MAX | FLIGHT_MAX | ORIGIN_MAX | DESINATION_MAX | DATE_FLIGHT_MAX    
> ----------: | :--------- | ---------: | :--------- | :------------- | :------------------ | :--------- | ---------: | :--------- | :------------- | :------------------
>         111 | LA         |        123 | LAX        | MIA            | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | LA         |        622 | SCL        | ARG            | 2020-02-05 08:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37158fc7e34b56bf1f72a930f6c1b451)*

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by reservation` to get the earliest and the latest date and then join this query to 2 copies of the table:

```
select 
  t.RESERVATION,
  t1.PREFIX PREFIX_min, 
  t1.FLIGHT FLIGHT_min, 
  t1.ORIGIN ORIGIN_min, 
  t1.DESTINATION DESTINATION_min, 
  t1.DATE_FLIGHT DATE_FLIGHT_min,
  t2.PREFIX PREFIX_max, 
  t2.FLIGHT FLIGHT_max, 
  t2.ORIGIN ORIGIN_max, 
  t2.DESTINATION DESTINATION_max, 
  t2.DATE_FLIGHT DATE_FLIGHT_max
from (
  select 
    RESERVATION,
    min(DATE_FLIGHT) DATE_FLIGHT_min, 
    max(DATE_FLIGHT) DATE_FLIGHT_max
  from tablename
  group by RESERVATION
) t
inner join tablename t1 on t1.RESERVATION = t.RESERVATION AND t1.DATE_FLIGHT = t.DATE_FLIGHT_min
inner join tablename t2 on t2.RESERVATION = t.RESERVATION AND t2.DATE_FLIGHT = t.DATE_FLIGHT_max
```

This will return 1 row for each reservation if there are no duplicate dates.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=716e78161feef7292b994b338a30f857).
Results:

```
> RESERVATION | PREFIX_MIN | FLIGHT_MIN | ORIGIN_MIN | DESTINATION_MIN | DATE_FLIGHT_MIN  | PREFIX_MAX | FLIGHT_MAX | ORIGIN_MAX | DESTINATION_MAX | DATE_FLIGHT_MAX  
> ----------: | :--------- | ---------: | :--------- | :-------------- | :--------------- | :--------- | ---------: | :--------- | :-------------- | :---------------
>         111 | LA         |        123 | LAX        | MIA             | 2020-02-01 00:00 | LA         |        622 | SCL        | ARG             | 2020-02-05 08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit similar to @forpas but using CTE

```
with min_max
as
(
select 
distinct reservation,
min(date_flight) over(partition by reservation) as date_flight_min,
max(date_flight) over(partition by reservation) as date_flight_max
from tablename 
)
select
m.reservation,
t1.prefix as prefix_min,
t1.flight as flight_min,
t1.origin as origin_min,
t1.destination as destination_min,
m.date_flight_min,
t2.prefix as prefix_max,
t2.flight as flight_max,
t2.origin as origin_max,
t2.destination as destination_max,
m.date_flight_max
from
min_max m
join tablename t1 on t1.date_flight=m.date_flight_min
join tablename t2 on t2.date_flight=m.date_flight_max
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b0115c8e47edd272b99c027718843fa9)